# Where can I upload and print photos on metallic paper?

Tags: printing

I used to use KodakGallery.com to print 8x10 photos with a metallic reflective finish.  Since the last time I printed a photo, KodakGallery.com has shut down and shutterfly has replaced it and I don't see an option to print photos with a metallic finish.

What is a good site for printing photos with a metallic finish?

Comment: I just ordered a couple prints from AdoramaPix -- they were on sale (ended Tuesday), but I haven't received them yet, so I'll reserve judgement as far as "good" goes.  Given their quality for other prints, though, I'd be surprised if they're not good.

Comment: I'll second AdoramaPix. I'm there for the books, mostly (I give my mid-sized printing to a fastidious local guy who's charging way less than he's worth), but they haven't let me down yet.

Comment: Also SmugMug.com has metallic prints http://www.smugmug.com/prints/metallic-paper (note, I'm an employee)

Comment: MPix has specialized in this for a great deal of time. They are nice prints, and Mpix is very popular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use smugmug.com for my hosting and printing services. They have Kodak metallic paper available for Pro users who choose Bay Photo as their printer. So I would guess that this means that Bay Photo also has the metallic paper available.

Answer (score 2):

Whitewall from Germany can print on aluminium, though I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Bumblejax is a great, professional-quality service that mounts digital photos to acrylic, aluminum, gator board and bamboo. They also include a metallic paper option. You can check them out here:http://www.bumblejax.com/

Comment: Hi Marina! Have you used this service? (Or, are you affiliated with them? Either is okay, but it'd be nice to have more details so people can make an informed choice.)

Comment: I have used this service several times. I've had a couple larger prints made and a few iphone photos printed on smaller canvases :)

Answer (score 1):

I used [FullColor](http://www.fullcolor.com/metal_products/metal_prints.aspx) based out of Dallas, TX, USA and was pleased with the price and quality of a reflective metal print.